# The best way to implement different behaviour's using the same abstraction

Tags: c#, design-patterns, unity-game-engine

actually i'm developing a weapon system on unity where you can mount a weapon with three different kind of bullets and i have same structure for bullet prefab but the movement logic should be different for each one. I'm having problems with GetComponent to find abstracted scripts and interfaces, i'm searching for a good solution to implement this architecture. Thanks!

```
public class BaseBullet : MonoBehaviour, IBullet { .... } 
interface IBullet { .. void shoot(vector2 direction); } 
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon 
{ ... BaseBullet bullet1; BaseBullet bullet2; BaseBullet bullet3 }
```

Comment: do u mean that your movement logic depends upon a> kind of bullet &  b>type of weapon ?

Comment: Strategy pattern to hold the movement logic in a separate strategy for each bullet, factory pattern to get the proper strategy.

Comment: Yes, but just in case A, should depends upon kind of bullet, it will works like type of ammo for the weapon.

Comment: Please post the code you are using.

Comment: BaseBullet.cs
public class BaseBullet : MonoBehaviour, IBullet { .... }
IBullet.cs
interface IBullet { .. void shoot(vector2 direction); }

BaseWeapon.cs
public class BaseWeapon : MonoBehaviour, IWeapon { ... BaseBullet bullet1; BaseBullet bullet2; BaseBullet bullet3 }

Comment: I'm using factory pattern on weapon to use the bullet choosen with an Enum.

Comment: I'm using the strategy like implementation and sucessfully works for the case. Thanks all you guys for the help.